# 2N3904 switching application

Tags: arduino, transistors, switching

I use 2N3904 as switch to power off/on the NEO-6M module control by Atmega328p.

I can draw until 96mA ( 100 mA ) .

I see on the stackexchange that Ib=Ic/10 to force full saturate the transistor.

Compute the current for base Ib :

Ib=Ic/10 
Ib=100/10 
Ib = 10mA

Compute the Rb :

Rb = (VCC - Vbe) / Ib 
Rb = (4 - 0.95 ) / ( 10 / 1000 )
Rb = 305 Ohm

But when i put 305ohm / 100ohm to base the gsm module power on but restart loop, I think Ic do not provide enough current.

I strange but when I connect the GPIO directly to the base it works ?

Note : I share the same VCC between the collector and base emitter (from my lithium battery).

Maybe the transistor is not design for my application maybe connect two transistor as darlington ?

Regards

Comment: Use a MOSFET for any low saturation voltage semi conductor switching applications over 50 mA.

Comment: individual transistors vary in hfe, i wouldn't worry about over-saturation from an mcu GPIO...

Comment: @Andyaka why is not possible with npn from the datasheet Ic can up to 100ma and 200mA absolute rating

Comment: The collector emitter saturation voltage will be 0.2 volts at 50 mA - that is 0.2 volts that your load won't ever get if it takes more than 50 mA. At higher load currents this will creep up. So 0.2 volts and 50 mA is equivalent to an "on resistance" of 4 ohms. Finding a small footprint mosfet that is one tenth of this value is really easy. At 100 mA the volt drop of a 2N3904 is about 0.35 volts.

Comment: @Andyaka - since the poster is inexperienced, you should have said, "Finding a small footprint _logic level_ mosfet ...".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the 2N3904 driven with 10 mA and controlling a 100 mA load: -

[image]

ON-SEMI data sheet was used for the above.

As you can see, the volt drop incurred (collector to emitter) is about 0.35 volts and this is lost across the transistor i.e. the 100 mA load doesn't receive 5 volts; it receives 4.65 volts and this may be enough to cause the problems you are seeing.

With the base connected directly to the IO pin you might be forcing 20 mA+ into the base and the volt drop might only be 0.3 volts across the transistor - this may be "borderline" OK and thus your system appears to work.

I would recommend using an N channel MOSFET having an on-resistance lower than 1 ohm to bottom this problem out - finding a logic level device capable of exhibiting a resistance less than 1 ohm should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply. What does mean the hFe in the datasheet ? because is not 30x like it say.

Comment: The data sheet says minimum hFE = 30 when Ic = 100 mA and Vce = 1 volt. That pretty much ties in with the 100 mA curve in my answer (base current 3 mA).

Comment: in the future i will watch the curve. I did just watch the table.

Comment: My recommendation for the N channel MOSFET is based on it switching the 0 V to the module BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Control U-blox +supply pin with an NPN transistor? I can only envision one way to do this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG4F4R.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above circuit is **bad practice**. The transistor switch has too much voltage drop when the GPIO pin goes high...even when you reduce R1 to zero ohms.
Use a high-side PNP switch instead:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOzzVH.png)</sup>
And if your GPS module really pulls 100mA current into its +supply pin, use a bigger transistor that can handle more current PN2907, 2N4403 or equivalent.
The saturation voltage in this case is far less than the NPN switch, and it won't get quite so hot.
Even better: Use a P-channel MOSfet having logic-level gate threshold voltage. You won't need a base-resistor (0 ohms) in this case.
Be aware that the GPIO switch logic is reversed with PNP high-side switch (same with P-channel MOSfet switch): To get your U-blox 6M powered up, the microcontroller GPIO pin is driven to **logic LOW**. To turn it off, GPIO is driven to **logic HIGH**. While the GPIO pin is high-impedance (tri-stated), the U-blox module will be inactive (off). However, if you use the P-channel MOSfet, a high-impedance GPIO pin will give you undefined power to U-blox, so in this case, the PNP transistor might be safer.

Comment: Yes thanks for your help. I used P-channel mofset (NDP6020P) with combinaison of NPN transistor. When my Arduino gpio is HIGH the P-channel mofset gate is pulled to gnd. it's work perfect and the voltage drop is only of 0.07v. I wanted to use NPN, because i would like a simple design.

Comment: In my module U-Blox 6M i see the regulator http://www.richtek.com/assets/product_file/RT9193/DS9193-16.pdf i has a "ENABLE PIN" i can use it to power on/off the module or it just for disable (bypass) ? Thanks by advance

Comment: @kiki67100 That regulator ENABLE pin looks good. Don't forget to add the 100K resistor between ENABLE and GND. You would drive ENABLE with a microcontroller GPIO output pin. Until GPIO becomes an "output", the 100K ensures that the regulator is OFF.